# JSON serialization fails with parent/child related entities in EF 6.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, entity-framework-6

I see that other folks have add issue with this error when trying to serialize an entity that has a navigation property to a collection of other entities such as in a parent child relationship.

```
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
```

I have tried added these options to the `Register` method inside the `WebApiConfig.cs` file but I still get the same error.

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to do this is to add

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

attributes in the entity for the references that you don't need to serialize  (I use buddy classes to annotate the entities). This is an example:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MenuItemValidation))]
public partial class MenuItem
{
public class MenuItemValidation
{
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Menu_Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Title { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Url { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int SortOrder { get; set; }
            public bool HasIcon { get; set; }
            public string IconClass { get; set; }
            public bool IsActive { get; set; }
            public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public System.Guid CreatedBy_Id { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public System.DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public System.Guid UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }
            public bool IsMegaMenu { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public virtual MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public virtual ICollection<MenuItemsLocalization> MenuItemsLocalizations { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I also added:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

inside App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs